# "The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details."

Tags: ejb

I have been using the tutorial below, and all I get is the error "The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.".

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

No matter how many projects I create, the same error is still there. When I try to deploy the enterprise application, it goes well. But when I later tries to start the application, it says that the module has not been deployed.

Comment: So, what's in the server log?

Answer (score 0):

- Exception while loading the app
- Undeployment failed for context /EntAppEJB-war
- Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: Virtual server
  server already has a web module EntAppEJB-war.war loaded at
  /EntAppEJB-war therefore web module EntAppEJB-war cannot be loaded at
  this context path on this virtual server

I had to remove one of the two EntAppEJB-war. It was very simple to solve.